# How to add 3rd party npm module/package to angular 8 app

Tags: angular, typescript, npm, angular8

So I am a complete newbie to angular and typescript so this can be pretty easy for community. I've surfed all around the web like for couple of hours and still I did not find a simple guide on how to add 3rd party module or package to my angular app.

The problem: I am trying to write a sort of rss reader. I found that this can be done by installing this npm package

https://www.npmjs.com/package/rss-to-json

I did try a lot of things already, but still no luck. I will show you the latest code I have for now in my service.

**http-requests.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Feed } from 'rss-to-json';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})

export class HttpRequestsService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  doDummyRequest() {
    return Feed.load('https://learnstartup.net/feed/', function(err, rss){
      console.log(rss);
    });
    // return this.http.get("https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/http://rss.cnn.com/rss/edition.rss");
  }

  displayDummyRequest() {
    this.doDummyRequest().subscribe((data: any) => {
      console.log(12346);
      console.log(data);
    });
  }
}
```

This code returns

```
RssFeedComponent.ngfactory.js? [sm]:1 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'load' of undefined
    at HttpRequestsService.doDummyRequest (http-requests.service.ts:15)
    at RssFeedComponent.onDummyButtonClick (rss-feed.component.ts:18)
    at Object.eval [as handleEvent] (RssFeedComponent.html:5)
    at handleEvent (core.js:43993)
    at callWithDebugContext (core.js:45632)
    at Object.debugHandleEvent [as handleEvent] (core.js:45247)
    at dispatchEvent (core.js:29804)
    at core.js:42925
    at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (platform-browser.js:2668)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone-evergreen.js:391)
```

Also my IDE (I use Visual Studio Code) displays a hint

```
Could not find a declaration file for module 'rss-to-json'. '/home/h8machine/App/news-agg/node_modules/rss-to-json/dist/index.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.
  Try `npm install @types/rss-to-json` if it exists or add a new declaration (.d.ts) file containing `declare module 'rss-to-json';`ts(7016)
```

Will appreciate any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[rss-to-json](https://github.com/nasa8x/rss-to-json) is NodeJs specific library so you won't be able to use it in the browser.

Comment: Is there a way to see if some libraries are node-only and which can be run in browser? Thank you.

Comment: In this case just because it is stated in the description of the github page. Just from a technical point of view it is possible to use the same package in both environments. Boils down to: It' depends on the library itself and it's dependencies (whether they are cross platform compatible or not)